# What is the correct way to remove multiple elements using ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I've been using python and ElementTree to manipulate rather large xml files with mixed success.  I find that I have difficulty removing multiple elements, especially when they are children of the root.  If I have 4 elements number 1-4 , only 1 and 3 will be removed using "for elem in root" clause.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CrossDEV culture-info="en-US" platform-version="2.40.8" product-version="2.40.8">
<MyStuff.Interface.Common.Objects.ActionItem ImportMode="Default">
    <TargetObjectKey>FOOSTUFF1</TargetObjectKey>
</MyStuff.Interface.Common.Objects.ActionItem>
<MyStuff.Interface.Common.Objects.ActionItem ImportMode="Default">
    <TargetObjectKey>FOOSTUFF2</TargetObjectKey>
</MyStuff.Interface.Common.Objects.ActionItem>
<MyStuff.Interface.Common.Objects.ActionItem ImportMode="Default">
    <TargetObjectKey>FOOSTUFF3</TargetObjectKey>
</MyStuff.Interface.Common.Objects.ActionItem>
<MyStuff.Interface.Common.Objects.ActionItem ImportMode="Default">
    <TargetObjectKey>FOOSTUFF4</TargetObjectKey>
</MyStuff.Interface.Common.Objects.ActionItem>
</CrossDEV>
```

Code:

```
def RemoveElementActionItem():
        sTag = 'SourceObjectKey'
        sTag2 = 'TargetObjectKey'
        sPattern = 'CHE-ZUG'
        r=0
        e=0
        global myroot
        if myroot is not None:
                print ('Root:', myroot)
                for elem in myroot:
                        e+=1
                        print ('Elem:',e, elem)
                        aRemove = True
                        bRemove = True
                        o = elem.find(sTag)
                        if o is not None and o.text.find(sPattern,0) > -1:
                                aRemove = False

                        p = elem.find(sTag2)
                        if o is not None and o.text.find(sPattern,0) > -1:
                                bRemove = False

                        if bRemove and aRemove:
                                myroot.remove(elem)
                                r+=1
                                print ('Removed:', myroot, elem)
                        else:
                                print ('   Keep:', myroot, elem, o , p, aRemove, bRemove)
        return r
```

In the code above I am searching the grandchildren for specific text values.  I've cobbled together a simple xml file that each ActionItem fails it's test, and therefore should be removed.  Instead only 2 of the 4 get removed.

My guess is that when the first from the list is removed, the addresses change so that the second is skipped.  Next the 3rd one is removed and the list shifts forward again.

Since in this simple case all 4 elements should be removed, what is a better way to construct my code?  I'd prefer to stick to the same library if I can since I've invested lots of time in it and haven't explored lxml or other libraries yet.

Note, I've been playing with different ways to scope the root object (myroot).  I've had it as a parameter, a return value and here as a global.  I've had the same results each way.

Comment: Please excuse my typo in the title, its been a long night!

Comment: Golden rule: never remove elements while iterating. Didn't try, but are you sure that the above code (on the above *XML*) does what you claim? It seems that `aRemove` will never be true.

Comment: That is correct, aRemove will never be true because the xml is just a subset of the data.  What I should have done was simplified the code.  Your Golden Rule is well taken, I should break out of the for loop at the first removal and start over again.  Thanks for responding and dealing with the extra code.

Comment: That took care of it.  I just break out of the first for loop and call the function again, this resets the counters and goes hunting again.  Thank You!  I tried to up vote your comment but accidentally turned it off again.  Put it in an answer and I'll gladly vote it up again.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing, aRemove will never be false.  Using reverse logic there, note aRemove and bRemove are initialized True.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. I will write an answer to illustrate the problem on a simple example (have to do a little research on *ElementTree* as I didn't use it for some time :) ).

Answer (score 0):

*code.py*:

```
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


XML_STR = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootNode>
  <ChildNode DummyIndex="0">
    <GrandChildNode DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode>
    <GrandChildNode_ToRemove DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToRemove>
  </ChildNode>
  <ChildNode DummyIndex="1">
    <GrandChildNode_ToDelete DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToDelete>
    <GrandChildNode_ToRemove DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToRemove>
  </ChildNode>
  <ChildNode DummyIndex="2">
    <GrandChildNode DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode>
    <GrandChildNode_ToDelete DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToDelete>
    <GrandChildNode_ToRemove DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToRemove>
  </ChildNode>
  <ChildNode DummyIndex="3">
    <GrandChildNode_ToRemove DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToRemove>
    <GrandChildNode_ToRemove DummyIndex="1">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToRemove>
  </ChildNode>
  <ChildNode DummyIndex="4">
    <GrandChildNode_ToDelete DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToDelete>
    <GrandChildNode_ToRemove DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToRemove>
    <GrandChildNode_ToDelete DummyIndex="1">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToDelete>
  </ChildNode>
  <ChildNode DummyIndex="5">
    <GrandChildNode_ToDelete DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToDelete>
  </ChildNode>
  <ChildNode DummyIndex="6">
    <GrandChildNode DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode>
    <GrandChildNode_ToRemove DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToRemove>
  </ChildNode>
  <ChildNode DummyIndex="7">
    <GrandChildNode_ToDelete DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode_ToDelete>
    <GrandChildNode_ToRemove DummyIndex="0">____OTHERTEXT____</GrandChildNode_ToRemove>
    <GrandChildNode DummyIndex="0">GrandChildText</GrandChildNode>
  </ChildNode>
  <ChildNode DummyIndex="8"/>
</RootNode>
"""

REMOVE_GRANDCHILD_TAGS = ["GrandChildNode_ToDelete", "GrandChildNode_ToRemove"]
REMOVE_GRANDCHILD_TEXT = "Child"


def is_node_subject_to_delete(node):
    removable_child_nodes_count = 0
    for remove_tag in REMOVE_GRANDCHILD_TAGS:
        for child_node in node.findall(remove_tag):
             if REMOVE_GRANDCHILD_TEXT in child_node.text:
                removable_child_nodes_count += 1
                break
    return removable_child_nodes_count == len(REMOVE_GRANDCHILD_TAGS)


def main():
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    #print(XML_STR)
    root_node = ET.fromstring(XML_STR)
    print("Root node has {:d} children\n".format(len(root_node.findall("ChildNode"))))
    to_remove_child_nodes = list()
    for child_node in root_node:
        if is_node_subject_to_delete(child_node):
            to_remove_child_nodes.append(child_node)
    print("Removing nodes:")
    for to_remove_child_node in to_remove_child_nodes:
        print("\n  Tag: {}\n  Text: {}\n  Attrs: {}".format(to_remove_child_node.tag, to_remove_child_node.text.strip(), to_remove_child_node.items()))
        root_node.remove(to_remove_child_node)
    print("\nRoot node has {:d} children\n".format(len(root_node.findall("ChildNode"))))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- `XML_STR`: example *xml* (could be also placed in a separate file)

  - Consists of a **root node** ("*RootNode*") that has a number (>= 0) of child nodes ("*ChildNode*"):
  - Each child node:

    - Is named "*ChildNode*"
    - Has a number (>= 0) of child nodes of their own ("*GrandChildNode**")
    - Each child (root grand child) node:

      - Has one of the following names (I guess the name endings are more than self explanatory):

        1. "*GrandChildNode*"
        2. "*GrandChildNode_ToDelete*"
        3. "*GrandChildNode_ToRemove*"
      - Has a text (might be `NULL`, empty or simply consisting of non printable *char*s)
- `REMOVE_GRANDCHILD_TAGS` - List of tag names, so that if a (root child) node has children matching **all** tags in the list, it can be removed - replacement of `sTag` and `sTag2` - (check `is_node_subject_to_delete` notes below), 
  If another tag (e.g. `GrandChildNode_ToErase`) is needed, it can **just be added it to the list** (no other *copy* / *paste* operations needed)
- `REMOVE_GRANDCHILD_TEXT` - A 2<sup>nd</sup> condition to the previous item: if the node text name **contains** that text ("*Child*") - if **both conditions are met**, the node is *delete*able
- `is_node_subject_to_delete(node)` - checks whether the argument (`node`-  root child) can be deleted:

  - Rules, as above (**both** have to be true (**&&**)):

    1. If the tag is in the *blacklist* (`REMOVE_GRANDCHILD_TAGS`) - instead of duplicating code, it's a `for` (outermost) loop
    2. If the text contains the "doomed" text
- `main` - A general wrapper function

  - As seen, only nodes with index **1**, **2** and **4** (**0** based) are suitable for deletion
  - Interface to the user
  - I propose iterating over the root child nodes **once** (the **golden rule**: "*never invalidate the iterable iterating on*" - which happened in your case), and for each node, if *delete*able, save it to a list (due to the fact that *Python* works with references, it's not costly), and at the end, delete all elements in that list (if any)
  - It's definitely more efficient than "*break out of the loop*" suggested (especially when dealing with **huge** number of root child nodes)

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049667831>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Root node has 9 children
>
> Removing nodes:
>
>   Tag: ChildNode
>   Text:
>   Attrs: [('DummyIndex', '1')]
>
>   Tag: ChildNode
>   Text:
>   Attrs: [('DummyIndex', '2')]
>
>  Tag: ChildNode
>   Text:
>   Attrs: [('DummyIndex', '4')]
>
> Root node has 6 children
> ```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer here is very useful, I personally was not able make use of it as I was unable to have each child have the same name. Instead, the way that I ended up iterating through my Element Tree was with a while loop, where I decrement the end variable (instead of incrementing the counter) in cases where I have to remove a child.

By reducing the end target, you avoid "out of bounds" errors

Here's an example of what this looks like just iterating through a string for simplicity:

```
i = 0
word = 'Python'
end = len(word)

while i < end:
    letter = word[i]
    if letter == 'h':
        word = word.replace(letter, '')
        end-=1
        continue
    print('Current Letter :' + letter)
    i+=1
```

If you apply this to an element tree, the code looks more or less the same, except instead of using `replace` on a char in a string, you'll use `root.remove(child)` where `child = root[i]`

I hope this is able to help someone. Thanks for reading.

Comment: The question is "What is the correct way to remove multiple elements using ElementTree?". This is not an answer to that question. Your code has nothing to do with XML.

Comment: Apologies, I suppose I could've been more clear with the application here. This code segment demonstrates the concept I applied to my Element Tree. 

The issue being experienced in the asker's problem is one of indexing: using a for loop to remove elements inherently messes up your indexing. The other answer here provides an in-depth solution, but that solution has some caveats. For one, he requires control over the names of the nodes he's removing, which isn't always something you can do.

Comment: The solution I provided attempts to show a way around the indexing issue, the code for this algorithm with an Element Tree is much the same, but would require more irrelevant code (declarations, etc) and thus introduce ambiguity. I used a string as an example to show the concept in action, and gave some notes on what changes would be made to apply this to an Element Tree, though I can see how some edits would be helpful to make my answer more clear